# Windows Security Auto Login

Tags: javascript, authentication, login

I have this problem that one of our landing page(Wiki) in our sharepoint site has a dashboard that is getting data from a non sharepoint site and you need to login in order to view this. But not all of our users has that account. So we created a dummy account that needs to be inputted in order to view the dashboard. What i want to happen is to create a javascript program in script editor that will automatically login when the windows security dialog box appear.

[image]

also our landing page is all HTML and CSS so i can easily add the javascript in case this is possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**No solution from SharePoint side**, also JS doesn't help in this situation,

You should manage the security from the dashboard side by allowing the **SSO** or the anonymous access to the dashboard URL!

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherently flawed plan of approach. You need to consider the risk of exposing that user name and password to anyone with access to that page.

Your are attempting to circumvent a security mechanism. SharePoint nor JS will assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Sharepoint BI Dashboard, or the Dashboard is created by separate product? If the earlier you should look into concept of using Unattended Account. If it is 3-rd party product you should look at their API documentation how to properly integrate it. Like previous answers trying to embed credentials in the JS is very bad idea (update your CV and look for new job if someone from security will discover it). If you external Dashboard is within you AD maybe you can set up permission that all Authenticated Users can access it this way everyone on your network can see it but it still not available to Anonymous users.